# PDO postgresql last inserted id return 'false' or -1

Tags: postgresql, pdo, lastinsertid

I have code

```
$dbh = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost; port=5432; dbname=gpd; user=postgres; password=postgres");
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO res (res_name, res_order) VALUES ('London', 1)");
$sth->execute();
$id = $dbh->lastInsertId();
echo $id;
```

Record insert, but $id is empty.

I try execure query 
`INSERT INTO res (res_name, res_order) VALUES ('London', 1) RETURNING id`

and received a value "-1"

Comment: Could you share the table structure of `res` please?

Comment: CREATE TABLE res
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  res_name VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  res_order INT DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going home, I myself understood what must to do

```
$dbh = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost; port=5432; dbname=gpd; user=postgres; password=postgres");    
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO res (res_name, res_order) VALUES ('London', 1)");    
$sth->execute();    
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
echo "ID - ". $result["id"];
```

It's simple